# Error when trying to configure Puppet to be highly available

Tags: puppet, high-availability

I want to configure puppet in a high availability environment. I have configured 2 Puppet masters but they are not able to sign each other by CA. When I try to test `puppet agent --test`, it gives me following error:

```
'Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/home/clogeny/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Error: /File[/home/clogeny/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/pluginfacts: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Wrapped exception:
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/home/clogeny/.puppet/var/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Error: /File[/home/clogeny/.puppet/var/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/plugins: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Wrapped exception:
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known'
```

Could anyone help me out?

Puppet.conf:

```
[main] 
logdir=/var/log/puppet 
vardir=/var/lib/puppet 
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl 
rundir=/var/run/puppet 
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter 
templatedir=$confdir/templates 
hiera_config=/etc/puppet/hiera.yml 
catalog_format = yaml 
certname=puppet 
pluginsync=false 
dns_alt_names=puppetmaster01,puppet.sencha.com 

[master] 
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN 
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY 
manifest=$confdir/manifests/site.pp 
modulepath=$confdir/environments/$environment/modules:/home/clogeny/Desktop/pupp‌​‌​et-kitchen-example/modules
```

Comment: Could you show puppet.conf files of your puppet master machines.

Comment: `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known` implies the Puppet master you have in your puppet.conf is not reachable, can you edit to show your config?

Comment: @kkamilpl,@PeterSouter My master machine puppet.conf file is :

 `[main] logdir=/var/log/puppet vardir=/var/lib/puppet ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl rundir=/var/run/puppet factpath=$vardir/lib/facter templatedir=$confdir/templates hiera_config=/etc/puppet/hiera.yml catalog_format = yaml certname=puppet pluginsync=false dns_alt_names=puppetmaster01,puppet.sencha.com [master] ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY manifest=$confdir/manifests/site.pp modulepath=$confdir/environments/$environment/modules:/home/clogeny/Desktop/pupp‌​et-kitchen-example/modules`

Answer (score 2):

There is missing [server](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#server) value in `[main]` section of [puppet.conf](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html). The `server` value should point to the Puppet master server. Name of the Puppet master server must be reachable from puppet agent. Check the following articles how to properly connect Puppet agent to puppet master:

http://shapeshed.com/connecting-clients-to-a-puppet-master/

https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html

Comment: Does any one have idea to configure multiple puppetmaster in HA (i.e. High Availability) environment?

I have two puppet master up and running but i am facing problem to configure in HA.

Comment: @sencha7 check the following reference https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/1740/how-to-design-a-high-available-multi-master-puppet-architecture-spanning-multiple-data-center/

Comment: I am getting following error after singing my client/node on puppet master and i try to run `puppet agent --test`. Can you please help me out?

Comment: And if i re-run `puppet agent` than getting above error  (which is posted on top of this issue) . 
And i am able to ping my puppet master from my node.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a name resolution issue? Both system( master & agent ) able to communicate using their FQDN? You can add their FQDN on /etc/hosts file if you don't/won't bother to use DNS server.

eg: /etc/host

```
root@puppet-master-kasun:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.1  puppet puppet-master

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

use  puppet agent -t --DEBUG to Debug

---

Debug: Starting connection for https://toto.local:8140
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

There  https://toto.local:8140 is unreachable